# Excel VBA, count letters which are bold and give an average

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names in excel and some of them are in bold. I have to create a VBA programm(macro), which gives an average of the length of names, which are written in bold.(counts how many letters are in the list of names which are bold and gives the average). Can anybody help me? I would really appreciate it.

This is the list of names.

**hanna**

hanna-liisa

hanna-maria

**hanna-stina**

hannaliisa

helga-marie

helgi-maie

helgi-maret

**helju-laine**

helju-marie

...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .In short, you'll need to show your code attempts to solve this and where it's not working to get the most help on this site. If you also post a screenshot of a sample of your sheet, that would help us help you more as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Font.Bold` property? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823025.aspx)

Comment: Loop, for each cell that is bold, length=length+`len`, increment total by 1, at end of loop, length/total for average?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
Sub AverageBold()
i = 1
j = 1
    'activate the appropriate sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    For Each cell In [A1:A10]
        j = j + 1
        If cell.Font.Bold = True Then i = i + 1
    Next cell
    MsgBox (i / j)
End Sub
```